# tagging connected components using networkx

Tags: python, networkx, igraph

Using `igraph` I'm able to assign unique id of connected component for each node:

```
import igraph 
def tag_components(vertices, edges):
    graph = igraph.Graph()
    graph.add_vertices(vertices)
    graph.add_edges(edges)
    graph_tags = graph.clusters().membership
    return graph_tags
print(tag_components([0,1,2,3,4,5], [[1,2],[2,4],[3,5]]))
```

It outputs `[0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]` which means that are 3 connected components indexed `0`, `1`, `2` consistent of node groups `[0]`, `[1, 2, 4]`, `[3, 5]`. How can I achieve the same output using `networkx?`

I expect something like:

```
def tag_components_nx(vertices, edges):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from(vertices)
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    ...
    return graph_tags
```

#### Update

I have a satisfactory answer already and I wonder if `networkx` has more sophisticated methods than `connected_components` suitable for my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the output of [`nx.connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components) you can build the desired output format.

Example.

```
>>> g.nodes()
NodeView((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
>>> g.edges()
EdgeView([(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 5)])
>>> idx_components = {u:i for i,node_set in enumerate(nx.connected_components(g)) for u in node_set}
>>> res = [idx_components[u] for u in vertices]
>>> res
[0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: No doubt, `connected_components` is the most popular method of `networkx` I use. Thanks for your example, I'll test it and try to make it consistent with `numpy` actions too, if possible.

Comment: It's a huge bonus if someone offers more sophisticated methods than `connected_components` too.

Comment: The algorithm used by networkx is a `bfs` performed for each not already visited node which is linear in the number of nodes and edges. Why would you need a more sophisticated method?

Comment: It takes a little time to think of solution like yours and I'm not an expert of `networkx` so I wonder if they have alternatives.

Comment: Btw, I use `networkx` only for demonstration purposes, that's why I'm looking for something like `common ways` to solve it.